# ajaxComplete, previously array empty

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
   // Start
   <div id="ms">
   <img src="img1.jpg"> 
   <img src="img2.jpg">
   </div>

   // After Ajax Completion
   <div id="ms">
   <img src="img3.jpg"> 
   <img src="img4.jpg">
   </div>

    var ik = new Array();

    var ls = function(){         
    $('#ms img').each(function() {
    ik.push($(this).attr("src"));    
    });  
    return ik;          
    }  

    var bs = function() {
    ls();  //img1.jpg, img2.jpg
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings){         
    ls(); //img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg, img4.jpg  should be only img3.jpg, img4.jpg
    });  
    return ik; 
    };

    console.log(bs());
```

I want before Ajaxcompletion, the array is empty (img1.jpg and img2.jpg).

If I do so I get no values​​:

ik = [];

For your help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem - you are repeating your ID's, they should be unique. After the first call to `ls()` the array `ik` will contain:

```
0: "img1.jpg"
1: "img2.jpg"
2: "img3.jpg"
3: "img4.jpg"
```

Second problem - you never reset the array `ik`, so each successive call to `ls()` will simply add the same four values. Though it appears that *may* have just been for debugging on your part.

Most importantly though, you are logging the return value of the `bs` function (aptly named in this case) but you likely should be waiting for ajaxComplete to be called before logging any results.

I'm not sure what your intention is with the `ik` array is, but when using asynchronous calls you should be using a callback pattern (or async pattern of your choice).

Something like:

```
var bs = function(callback) {
    $('document').ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
        callback(…your result here…);
    });
};

bs(function(result) {
   console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Okay. I quickly built up here as an example the HTML code. Original is the thing more complicated. :-)

I get images URL and I build a Gallery. Before Ajax call, I would like ik empty.

Comment: It's the return value from an async function that is the real problem here.

Comment: The problem is not emptied before the Ajax call var ik. New pictures are always Adding Ajax to call it. But I want to empty ik before calling Ajax and new imgs.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find that code on your site, but you could just simple set `ik.length = 0` in the appropriate location if you just need to empty the array.

Comment: oh, instead ik = []; ?

Comment: If you never assign the value of `ik` to anything else - that will work as well.

Comment: ok. Thank you very much. ik.length = 0 work fine form me. :-)